# QGIS : building ok, installation failed (linker error ?)

Tags: qgis

I want to do some coding with QGIS. I work with Ubuntu 14.04 trusty. I followed the instructions [here](http://linfiniti.com/2011/06/using-qtcreator-with-qgis/) to build QGIS with Qtcreator.

When trying to build, the following issue appears :

```
:-1: error: [src/core/CMakeFiles/qgis_core.dir/gps/context.c.o] Error 1
```

I did not understand the error, so I tried to build QGIS with the console, and it worked, but I could not fix the installation step : when I type `make install` , I get the following warning code :

```
Linking CXX executable CMakeFiles/CMakeRelink.dir/qgis.r.in6
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libgrass_datetime.6.4.3.so, needed by /usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gis.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

However, the file /usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_datetime.6.4.3.so does exist, and I do not understand why I get this warning only for the grass library when many others are needed.

I get many other lines of undefined reference related to libgrass package like :
    /usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_vect.so: undefined reference to `dig__fwrite_port_L'

All of this resulting with :

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/providers/grass/6/CMakeFiles/CMakeRelink.dir/qgis.r.in6] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/providers/grass/6/CMakeFiles/qgis.r.in6.dir/preinstall] Error 2
make: *** [preinstall] Error 2
```

Does anybody know about this error and its meaning ?
Here's the result of typing `ls -l /usr/lib/grass64/lib/ | grep libgrass`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14400 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_arraystats.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_arraystats.so -> libgrass_arraystats.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14432 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_bitmap.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_bitmap.so -> libgrass_bitmap.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10144 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_btree.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_btree.so -> libgrass_btree.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27104 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_cairodriver.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     29 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_cairodriver.so -> libgrass_cairodriver.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47520 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_cdhc.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_cdhc.so -> libgrass_cdhc.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14456 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_cluster.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_cluster.so -> libgrass_cluster.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35328 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_datetime.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_datetime.so -> libgrass_datetime.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68976 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dbmibase.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dbmibase.so -> libgrass_dbmibase.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44120 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dbmiclient.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dbmiclient.so -> libgrass_dbmiclient.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31688 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dbmidriver.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dbmidriver.so -> libgrass_dbmidriver.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10184 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dbstubs.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dbstubs.so -> libgrass_dbstubs.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  97416 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dgl.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dgl.so -> libgrass_dgl.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  81024 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dig2.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dig2.so -> libgrass_dig2.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48064 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_display.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_display.so -> libgrass_display.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48224 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_driver.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_driver.so -> libgrass_driver.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14368 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dspf.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_dspf.so -> libgrass_dspf.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27536 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_edit.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_edit.so -> libgrass_edit.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18824 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_form.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_form.so -> libgrass_form.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 131104 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_g3d.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_g3d.so -> libgrass_g3d.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 346712 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_gis.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_gis.so -> libgrass_gis.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26768 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_gmath.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_gmath.so -> libgrass_gmath.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 109624 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_gpde.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_gpde.so -> libgrass_gpde.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39584 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_gproj.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_gproj.so -> libgrass_gproj.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43640 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_I.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10224 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_interpdata.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_interpdata.so -> libgrass_interpdata.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  64304 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_interpfl.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_interpfl.so -> libgrass_interpfl.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43608 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_Iortho.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_Iortho.so -> libgrass_Iortho.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  34882 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_iostream.6.4.3.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43200 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_ismap.6.4.3.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_I.so -> libgrass_I.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35352 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_lidar.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_lidar.so -> libgrass_lidar.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10232 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_linkm.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_linkm.so -> libgrass_linkm.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14440 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_lrs.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_lrs.so -> libgrass_lrs.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47926 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_manage.6.4.3.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35352 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_neta.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_neta.so -> libgrass_neta.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  40152 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_nviz.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_nviz.so -> libgrass_nviz.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 409032 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_ogsf.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_ogsf.so -> libgrass_ogsf.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27048 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_pngdriver.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_pngdriver.so -> libgrass_pngdriver.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18624 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_psdriver.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_psdriver.so -> libgrass_psdriver.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10216 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_qtree.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_qtree.so -> libgrass_qtree.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48944 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_raster.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_raster.so -> libgrass_raster.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35448 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_rli.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_rli.so -> libgrass_rli.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10200 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_rowio.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_rowio.so -> libgrass_rowio.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22712 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_rtree.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_rtree.so -> libgrass_rtree.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14392 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_segment.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_segment.so -> libgrass_segment.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39176 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_shape.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_shape.so -> libgrass_shape.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47448 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_sim.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_sim.so -> libgrass_sim.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27256 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_sites.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_sites.so -> libgrass_sites.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43440 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_sqlp.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_sqlp.so -> libgrass_sqlp.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18464 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_stats.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_stats.so -> libgrass_stats.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18640 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_symb.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_symb.so -> libgrass_symb.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10232 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_trans.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_trans.so -> libgrass_trans.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18672 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_vask.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_vask.so -> libgrass_vask.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263880 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_vect.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_vect.so -> libgrass_vect.6.4.3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35280 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_vedit.6.4.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 déc.  16  2013 libgrass_vedit.so -> libgrass_vedit.6.4.3.so
```

Comment: You should add more information. What OS and compiler do you use, etc.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the post to give more precisions. However, it seems that [this link](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/) give me some answers.

Comment: Can you show result of `ls -l /usr/lib/grass64/lib/ | grep libgrass`?

Comment: Done. I edited the post. To answer your previous question on the compiler, I don't know, I use a `ccmake ..` to configure the stuff, and I don't find info on the compiler.

Comment: To realize what compiler do you use you can call make with VERBOSE option like: `make VERBOSE=1` and see full commands. But unfortunately I have no idea about your problem. All I can suggest is just try to compile the project one more time using [official instruction](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL) or ask this question as [suggested on official site](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/support.html).